# Web server based on expressions

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm attempting to create a web server that calls functions based on regular expression matches.  Below is an example.  However, I'm having trouble calling the matching function.  This code causes node.js to crash saying that the object method is not a function.  What am I doing wrong?

```
http = require "http"

http.createServer( (req, res) ->
    res.writeHead 200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
    res.end handle req
).listen 8080

console.log "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/"

paths = [
    method: home, expression: "/"
    method: user, expression: "/user"
]

home = (req) ->
    return "This is the home"

user = (req) ->
    return "This is a user page"

handle = (req) ->
    for path in paths
        if req.url.match path.expression
            console.log path.expression
            return path.method req
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `home`/`user` aren't defined at the time `paths` is created.
- `paths` won't be an array of objects in that way. (See [FAQ](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ).)

Try:

```
http = require "http"

http.createServer (req, res) ->
    res.writeHead 200, "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    res.end handle req
.listen 8080

console.log "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/"

home = (req) -> "This is the home"
user = (req) -> "This is a user page"

paths = [
    {} = method: home, expression: "/"
    {} = method: user, expression: "/user"
]

handle = (req) ->
    for path in paths
        if req.url is path.expression
            console.log path.expression
            return path.method req
```